# Unity/C#: How to disable component in animation state machine

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, animation

I'm trying to disable the BoxCollider2D on a gameObject obj when the animation state machine reaches a certain state. I've looked all over with no luck. Anything helps!

```
GameObject obj;
    
    void OnStateEnter(){
        obj.GetComponent<BoxCollider2D>().enabled = false;
    }
```

This is what I have, but I keep getting compiler errors. I'm relatively new to Unity and C# (although I have a solid background in C & C++).

Comment: Please use the correct tags! Note that [`unityscript`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/unityscript/info) is or better **was** a JavaScript flavor like custom language used in early Unity versions and is long **deprecated** by now! If you don't use that language don't use that tag.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have much experience with this, but I did some research into it. I think the issue might be you're class is not deriving from StateMachineBehaviour. It probably is still deriving from Monobehaviour. Take a look at this doc. https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/StateMachineBehaviour.html

If not, it could be because OnStateEnter requires parameters to work. The doc has an example, so I recommend trying that and see how it works.

PS: I think it might have been more helpful to the community if you mentioned what errors exactly you got. The compiler erros could have been for something else.